# How do I customize the UISearchBar scopes to be scrollable?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I would like to customize the UISearchBar such that the scope control is horizontally scrollable. I would further like to be able to customize the style and content of the items in the scope bar to include multiple labels and possibly an image.

I'm happy to elaborate if my description is too vague.